# Transparent Occlusion Shader in Unity URP

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader, renderer, urp, occlusion

I am struggling to find a way to make a transparent surface occlude opaque meshes behind it for an AR app. Often times, this is used to make "floating door" animations, holes in the ground, etc where a surrounding transparent mesh occludes anything that is not viewable through a hole in the mesh, and is a commonly used trick in Unity. It becomes an issue when trying to do it in URP.
[Above Occlusion Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nP4uT.png)
[Below Occlusion Cube](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBcZy.png)
[Below Occlusion Cube with pill highlighted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aLA18.png)

The closest thing I've found is this shader. It seems to be capturing the depth information correctly (?), but it is unable to render the cube transparent. It has eliminated the "smear" issue that others seem to be having with other transparent occlusion shaders in URP. I feel like maybe I'm missing something with the render layers, but I am not experienced enough in them to understand. Ideally, the top side view would just show the top half of the capsule, and the bottom side view would show nothing

```
Shader "Custom/InvisibleOcclusionShaderURP"
{
    Properties
    {
        [HDR] _BaseColor("Base Color", Color) = (1, 1, 1, 1)
        _MainTex("Texture", 2D) = "white" {}
    }
        SubShader
    {
        Tags {"Queue" = "Transparent" "RenderType" = "Transparent"}
        Pass
        {
            Stencil
            {
                Ref 1
                Comp always
                Pass replace
            }

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma multi_compile_fog

            #include "UnityCG.cginc"

            struct appdata_t
            {
                float4 vertex : POSITION;
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
            };

            struct v2f
            {
                float2 texcoord : TEXCOORD0;
                float4 vertex : SV_POSITION;
            };

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            float4 _MainTex_ST;

            v2f vert(appdata_t v)
            {
                v2f o;
                o.vertex = UnityObjectToClipPos(v.vertex);
                o.texcoord = TRANSFORM_TEX(v.texcoord, _MainTex);
                return o;
            }

            half4 frag(v2f i) : SV_Target
            {
                // Make the object invisible, but still write to the depth buffer.
                return half4(0, 0, 0, 0);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually this is achieved with a second camera at a heigher depth rather than a shader in the case of doors/portals as you want to render something through them (plenty of examples out there). In the case of holes... can you just cut a hole in the mesh, either at design time or run time?

Comment: Is it possible to create a second AR camera and have a mobile device use both? I'm still new to depth/render layers, so I could try to explore this more. And yes, I have a mesh with a hole cut in it, but the goal is to make it look like the hole is cut into the real-world ground in AR, not into a mesh that is rendered on top of the ground. So I would need the mesh to be transparent but at the same time occlude anything behind it that is not visible through the hole.